# After updating Android Studio and Android SDK Ionic project does't build anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic3

I tried to update Android Studio and Android SDK, until then my Ionic project was building with no problems (the APK, at least), so now I have this whey I try to run/build:

```
± % ionic cordova build andoid --prod --release                                                                                                                               !17
> cordova platform add andoid --save
Using cordova-fetch for andoid

Error: Failed to fetch platform andoid
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: andoid@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/francisco/.npm/_logs/2019-01-21T16_37_07_994Z-debug.log

[ERROR] Exception:
```

I think something went really wrong on that update, any ideas what would be?

Project settings:

```
± % ionic info                                                                                                                                                                !19

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
    ios-sim           : 6.0.0
    Node              : v8.11.3
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS
    Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/francisco/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

In Android Studio is still showing that I have something to update:
[image]

Then I try to run the Update and I get this:

```
Packages to install: 
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86)

Preparing "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 30)".
Failed to read or create install properties file.
Failed packages:
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86)
```

On Android SDK tab inside Android Studio I have this:
[image]